# Is it possible to use different UITableView styles for iPhone and iPad (and even Catalyst) in Storyboard based app?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistoryboard

I want to mimic the same UITableView styles as in the iOS Settings app. So I have a master view controller which is a UITableViewController with table view style 'Grouped'. And there is a detail view controller which is a UITableViewController with table view style 'Grouped' on iPhone and 'Grouped Inset' for iPads.

What is the best way to implement this behaviour in Storyboards. I can not seem to make this work.

If I have to do it with vary traits then I will have to maintain about 46 different traits because of all the device types.

I tried overriding the init function of the table view controller. But the override init(style: UITableView.Style) function is never called if it is Storyboard based.

I tried setting the style programmatically, but it is a read-only property.

Is there any way to do this in 1 storyboard?

[image: iPhone settings]
[image: iPhone general]
[image: iPad]

Answer (score 0):

If you create an iPadOS Storyboard View Controller and an iPhone one, each with a unique storyboardID then depending at runtime with .userInterfaceIdiom you detect, you can load directly from a storyboard file a view controller with that specific storyboardID

Answer (score -1):

You can check the device type and then make changes based on that:

```
print(UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom)
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
   print("running on iPhone")
}
```

Edit: I don't think that you can do that within the storyboard.

Comment: Yes, I know I can check the userInterfaceIdiom, but the style of a table view can not be set programmatically. It is read-only.

Comment: What if you would instantiate the table view programmatically? If it is a phone you can have a plain table view, otherwise group.